# Show map function's info in an expansion panel - RecactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, array.prototype.map

I would like to show map function's info (taken from a json file) in an expansion panel (react hook), clickng on a button:

```
<div>
<div>
{item.peapoleInfo.map((info, i) => {
return (
<img src={info.img} />
<h1> {info.name} </>
<button onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}> CLICK HERE </>
);
})}
</div>
{ expand && <div>
show same info clicking on button
<div>
}
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I have a json file with people info list. clicking on the button (related to each different image and name), I'd like to show the same image and name + addional info in the expansion panel.